# Dealing with non-standard time data

Tags: r, date, time, lubridate

I have some time data as part of a dataset -- let's call df, that is in a format which makes manipulation difficult. Let's call this time variable "time". Here's some example of the data:

```
df$time
12/17/2012
1945
1950
2032
2/24/2012
2206
2209
2211
```

As you can see, the time variable column starts with a given date (mm/dd/yyyy), and then is followed by the time (hhmm) a given event occurred on that same date.

Would it be possible to 'carry' down the month, day, and year values to the corresponding hour and time values? I'd like my data to ultimately look like this:

```
df$time
12/17/2012 19:45
12/17/2012 19:50
12/17/2012 20:32
2/24/2012  22:06
2/24/2012  22:09
2/24/2012  22:11
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you better explain the hour/minute data. Where does it come from? Also, in some of the rows you have only year or a combination of day/month, so that means it would be impossible to obtain a unified D/M/Y/H/S format if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: @Prometheus The entries with slashes in them are dates, and the four digit numbers below each date are times (albeit without a colon). So the third row under df$time would be 19:50 on Dec. 17th, 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert the format of your hours with:

```
time=gsub("^(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$","\\1:\\2",time)
```

Then locate the positions of the dates:

```
pos=grep("\\d+/\\d+/\\d+",time)
```

Then construct your result vector:

```
dates=rep(time[pos],times=(diff(c(pos,length(time)+1))-1))
hours=time[-pos]
time=paste(dates,hours)
```

Finally, you can convert it to `POSIXct` if you need to:

```
time=as.POSIXct(time,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: This seems to work quite well, thanks! I'll have to read up on regex.

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` style answer using `na.locf` from `zoo`. his works by separating the date and time into separate columns by presence of "/", carrying forward the dates with `na.locf`, filtering out the original date rows, pasting together the columns, and converting it to a `POSIXct`

```
df <- read.table(text=
"12/17/2012
1945
1950
2032
2/24/2012
2206
2209
2211
", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df) <- "original_time"

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(zoo)

df %>% 
  mutate(event_date = if_else(str_detect(original_time, "/"), original_time, as.character(NA)),
         event_time = if_else(str_detect(original_time, "/"), as.character(NA), original_time),
         event_date = na.locf(event_date)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(event_time)) %>%
  mutate(event_date_time = paste(event_date, event_time),
         event_date_time = as.POSIXct(event_date_time, format="%m/%d/%Y %H%M")) %>%
  select(event_date_time)

# event_date_time
# 1 2012-12-17 19:45:00
# 2 2012-12-17 19:50:00
# 3 2012-12-17 20:32:00
# 4 2012-02-24 22:06:00
# 5 2012-02-24 22:09:00
# 6 2012-02-24 22:11:00
```